# SpriteKit presentScene() Memory Leak

Tags: swift, memory, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a game with a **Menu Scene** and a **Game Scene**.
In the Menu Scene I start the Game with:

```
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
let scene = GameScene(size: self.scene!.size)
scene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
self.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

When the game is over I use the following code in the **Game Scene** to get back to the **Menu Scene**:

```
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
let scene = MenuScene(size: self.scene!.size)
scene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode

self.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

So far so simple. But with every transition the memory consumption increases.
Is there a possibility to avoid this? For example reuse the Menu Scene?

[image]

**This is how I load the first MenuScene in the GameViewController:**

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    var scene = MenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `deinit` to check the scene is be deallocated?

Comment: Are you sure you're not keeping any old references to your scenes. Also does your menu scene have a reference to your game scene and vice-versa. What about your GameViewController, does it keep a reference to any of these scenes.

Comment: @EpicByte Thanks for the tip with deinit. The Game Scene calls the deinit but not the Menu Scene. Maybe because I present the Menu Scene from the GameViewController?

Comment: Do you have a property that holds a reference to the MenuScene in the GameViewController?

Comment: Or do you only use a local variable to present the scene.

Comment: @EpicByte I have edited the question, so you can see how I load the first MenuScene.

Comment: Apple docs state the following: When the transition occurs, the scene property is immediately updated to point to the new scene. Then, the animation occurs. Finally, the strong reference to the old scene is removed. If you need to keep the scene around after the transition occurs, your app needs to keep its own strong reference to the old scene. So as long as you don't keep any references to the scene it should get deallocated.

Comment: I noticed that you are creating your menu scene in the viewWillLayout method. This is an appropriate spot, however you should check that it only runs once. ViewWillLayout could get called again. In fact can you put a NSLog inside that method and verify that it is only getting called once.

Comment: @EpicByte Now the MenuScene calls the `deinit` method. I have now idea why it is working now! But thank you very much  for your help.

Comment: @EpicByte The game now needs constantly around 60 MB of memory. Do you think that's okay for a 2D Game with graphics like Mega Jump.

Comment: @JonasEster Yes that's fine. What did you do to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81310/discussion-between-jonas-ester-and-epic-byte).

Comment: What exactly was the problem here?